# JPA Exception: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm developing a Spring MVC application with MySQL DB. Two of the tables in the database have a one to many relationship.

One of this tables is Quiz

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Quiz", schema = "QuizOwo")
public class QuizEntity
{
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "idQuiz")
    private int idQuiz;

   @Column(name = "nameQuiz")
    private String nameQuiz;

   @Column(name = "descriptionQuiz")
    private String descriptionQuiz;

   @ManyToOne(optional=false)
   @JoinColumn(name = "idCategory")
    private CategoryQuizEntity categoryQuizEntity;

   @Column(name = "idPortal")
    private int idPortal;
```

The other table is

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CategoryQuiz", schema = "QuizOwo")
public class CategoryQuizEntity
{
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "idCategoryQuiz")
    private int idCategoryQuiz;

   @Column(name = "nameCategory")
    private String nameCategory;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy="categoryQuizEntity", targetEntity=QuizEntity.class, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
   @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
     private List<QuizEntity> quizEntities;
```

My problem is that when a SQL statement is released (using hibernate JPA) the org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException is thrown with this information.

```
could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
```

¿Why?

---EDIT---

My mysql configuration is

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PersistenceConfig
{
    /** Bean para obtener el dataSource */
    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource getDataSource(){
       DataSource dataSource = createDataSource();
       return dataSource;
     }

    /** Generador del datasource */
    private DriverManagerDataSource createDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName(ConfigurationManager.getProperty(ConfigurationManager.DATABASE_DIVERCLASSNAME));
        driverManagerDataSource.setUrl(ConfigurationManager.getProperty(ConfigurationManager.DATABASE_URL));
        driverManagerDataSource.setUsername(ConfigurationManager.getProperty(ConfigurationManager.DATABASE_USERNAME));
        driverManagerDataSource.setPassword(ConfigurationManager.getProperty(ConfigurationManager.DATABASE_PASSWORD));
        driverManagerDataSource.setConnectionProperties(databaseProperties());
        return driverManagerDataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }


    /** Generamos un entityManagerFactory con lo paquetes donde tiene que escanear para buscar a las entidades, el datasource
 * las propiedades de hibernate... */
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() throws ClassNotFoundException, PropertyVetoException {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        emf.setDataSource(createDataSource());
        emf.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.owo.quiz.models" });
        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        emf.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return emf;
    }

    /** Propiedades para hibernate/JPA */
    Properties hibernateProperties() {
        return new Properties() {
            {
                setProperty("hibernate.dialect", ConfigurationManager.getProperty(ConfigurationManager.HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
                setProperty("hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers", "true");
            }
        };
    }

    /** Propiedades para la conexión con la base de datos */
    Properties databaseProperties() {
        return new Properties() {
            {
                setProperty("characterEncoding", "iso8859-1");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

=== EDIT ====

The SQL INSERT Quiz Table is

```
CREATE TABLE Quiz ( idQuiz int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, nameQuiz varchar(45) COLLATE latin1_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL, descriptionQuiz text COLLATE latin1_spanish_ci, idCategory int(11) DEFAULT NULL, idPortal int(11) DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (idQuiz), KEY fk_Quiz_1_idx (idCategory), CONSTRAINT fk_Quiz_1 FOREIGN KEY (idCategory) REFERENCES CategoryQuiz (idCategoryQuiz) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_spanish_ci;
```

Comment: can you share the sql create statement of table `Quiz`

Comment: see the edit question, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reset all MySQL permissions for this user and it worked correctly.

Comment: ...are you sure the mysql user permissions were the real problem? It makes no sense that that would have anything to do with the error message that you provided.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using spring , spring boot , spring data , JPA and Hibernate, try using below property:

**spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true**

If you are using hibernate only :

**hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true**

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the MySQL dialect as a part of your connection properties.

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

Comment: maybe try to obtain the sql to see, what JPA produces: SET GLOBAL general_log_file = '/var/log/mysql/mysql.log'; SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON'. In mysql as admin. This puts quite a bit of load on the system.

Comment: /var/log/mysql/mysql.log is empty

Comment: Sorry this's the mysql.log 

`select quizentity0_.idQuiz as idQuiz1_4_0_, quizentity0_.idCategory as idCatego5_4_0_, quizentity0_.descriptionQuiz as descript2_4_0_, quizentity0_.idPortal as idPortal3_4_0_, quizentity0_.nameQuiz as nameQuiz4_4_0_, categoryqu1_.idCategoryQuiz as idCatego1_2_1_, categoryqu1_.nameCategory as nameCate2_2_1_ 
from QuizOwo.Quiz quizentity0_ 
inner join QuizOwo.CategoryQuiz categoryqu1_ 
on quizentity0_.idCategory=categoryqu1_.idCategoryQuiz
where quizentity0_.idQuiz=2`

And if I run this in mysql console, the result is correct.